# Change file and folder permissions in Sublime Text 2

Tags: file-permissions, sublimetext2

Is there a way to change the permissions of a file or folder inside Sublime Text 2?

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle file's read-only flag in Sublime Text 2 using [toggle-readonly plugin](https://github.com/reflog/toggle-readonly).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping to find a plugin to change  permissions like unix based system do using chmod (read, write, excecute etc.)

Comment: Why not write such a plugin on your own? Sublime Text 2 has a very nice API.

Comment: Warning on the plugin - I just tried the plugin mentioned in the first comment, sadly it does not work after install on MtnLion. I logged it in GitHub and someone else said it didnt work for them on Windows8.